# jQuery loop through .hover( ) function using .each( )

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I have a function that changes the border-color of the arrows to match the hover state colour of the buttons. It is working as 3 separate functions but I want to combine them using .each( ) Please tell me where I am going wrong

[image]

**Vars**

```
var btnArrowPath = '.btn + .btn-arrow';
var btnName = ['btn-infra ','btn-dev ','btn-anal '];
var btnColor = ['#286090','#449d44','#31b0d5'];
var btnRollColor = ['#337ab7','#5cb85c','#5bc0de'];
```

**Function**

```
 $('.btn-wrap').each(function(i, value){
    $(btnName[value] + '.btn').hover(function(i, value){
      $(btnName[value] + btnArrowPath).css('border-top-color',btnColor[value]);
   }, function(){
      $(btnName[value] + btnArrowPath).css('border-top-color',btnRollColor[value]);
   });
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="hero-wrap">
                <div class="hero-popup">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="btn-wrap btn-infra">
                            <button data-trigger="focus" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="Infrastructure" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right? <a href='#'>Do it!</a>" data-placement="bottom">Infrastructure</button>
                            <div class="btn-arrow pull-right"></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="btn-wrap btn-dev">
                            <button data-trigger="focus" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="popover" title="Development" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right? <a href='#'>Do it!</a>" data-placement="top">Development</button>
                            <div class="btn-arrow pull-right"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="btn-wrap btn-anal">
                            <button data-trigger="focus" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="popover" title="Analysis" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right? <a href='#'>Do it!</a>" data-placement="top">Analysis</button>
                            <div class="btn-arrow pull-right"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>]
```

Comment: What does it currently do? It would be helpful if you gave the css of the buttons.

Comment: Hi Clinton:  I'm not sure where you are having a problem.  Could you please clarify what's going wrong?

Comment: it currently does nothing. the function works fine if I do not use the arrays. Currently the border-color on the arrow does not change

Comment: I found why my method was not working I forgot to add the period in front of the classes in this array var btnName = ['btn-infra ','btn-dev ','btn-anal '];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have the hover function for the `.btn` element inside the `.btn-wrap` element, which will change the border top color of the next sibling of the hovered element, isn't it?

So

```
$('.btn-wrap .btn').each(function (i, value) {
    $(this).hover(function (e) {
        $(this).next('.btn-arrow').css('border-top-color', btnColor[i]);
    }, function () {
        $(this).next('.btn-arrow').css('border-top-color', btnRollColor[i]);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3La3aste/)

---

You can do it without the loop like

```
var $btns = $('.btn-wrap .btn').hover(function (e) {
    $(this).next('.btn-arrow').css('border-top-color', btnColor[$btns.index(this)]);
}, function () {
    $(this).next('.btn-arrow').css('border-top-color', btnRollColor[$btns.index(this)]);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3La3aste/2/)